# Error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'Automatisation.DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx'

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been following [this thread](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/34037/datagridvewtextboxcell-with-span-behaviour#:%7E:text=var%20cell%20%3D%20%28DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx%29dataGridView1%20%5B0%2C%200%5D%3B%20cell.ColumnSpan%20%3D,to%20%282%2C%201%29%20%28see%20screenshot%20at%20the%20top%29.), but I get an error each time I try to convert a datagridview cell to a "DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx" object. How can I cast one into the other,so that I could merge some of my columns?

Here's my test code :

```
  var cell = (DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2[0, 0];
                cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
                cell.RowSpan = 1;
```

Each time it gives me the title exception.
Thanks for your help!